# How would I properly use malloc in this code to avoid a crash?

Tags: c, string, memory, crash, malloc

I am quite confused about where I need to use malloc, it keeps crashing. I am not sure if I need to reallocate memory when I navigate to the next slist.

```
struct string_list {
    char *s;
    struct string_list *next;
};

typedef struct string_list slist;

slist *sl_cons(char *s, slist *strings){
    slist *result = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
    result -> s = s;
    result -> next = strings;
    return result;
}

slist *sl_shallow_copy(slist *strings){
    slist *shallow = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
    while(strings != NULL){
        shallow->s = strings->s;
        shallow = shallow->next;
        strings = strings->next;
    }
    return shallow;
}

void sl_free(slist *strings){
    if(strings != NULL){
        sl_free(strings->next);
        free(strings->s);
        free(strings);
    }
```

Comment: What is `slist`?

Comment: Unrelated but don't cast the void *

Comment: If you do a shallow copy and free both the original and the copy, then `strings->s` will be freed twice, which results in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: There are problems in `sl_shallow_copy()`. `shallow->next` is uninitialized, so `shallow = shallow->next;` followed in the next iteration by `shallow->s = strings->s;` is an invalid pointer dereference resulting in UB.

Comment: "it keeps crashing" is not a problem description. Crashing how? Where? With what error message?

Answer (score 3):

1. In the expression `shallow = shallow->next` the right hand side (rhs) is not initialized which is undefined behavior (UB).  Anything can happen including a crash.
2. In `sl_shallow_copy()` you allocate `1` instance of `slist` but want to copy many from `strings.  Allocate new` slists` instances of your shallow copy in the loop.
3. If `malloc()` fails (however unlikely) your program would segfault due to NULL dereference.
4. `sl_cons()`: if you pass a regular string literal it will segfault when you try to free the read-only string.  If you want to free `s` then you want to make a copy it to ensure you can.
5. In `sl_free()`: Prefer an iterative algorithm to avoid blowing up the stack if there are too many nodes.  C does not guarantee tail call optimization (TCO) which means a sufficiently large number of nodes will below up the stack.
6. `sl_free()`: if you free both the original and the shallow clone the string will be free'ed twice which is UB.  You want to free the `slist` but not the shallow copied `s`.
7. You can tell `sl_cons()` and `sl_free()` if they operate on shallow or deep data, however, consider a reference count design instead.  `struct string_ref *sref` now holds our `char *` (copy) along with a count of references to to it `n`.  When we create the list we initialize `n` to `0`.  `sl_shallow_copy()` increments `n`, and `sl_free` decrements it unless it's `0` in which case we free both `sref->s` and `sref`.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L // strdup()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct string_ref {
    char *s;
    size_t n;
};

typedef struct string_list {
    struct string_ref *sref;
    struct string_list *next;
} slist;

slist *sl_cons(char *s, slist *strings) {
    slist *result = malloc(sizeof *result);
    if(!result)
        return NULL;
    result->sref = malloc(sizeof *result->sref);
    result->sref->s = strdup(s);
    result->sref->n = 0;
    result->next = strings;
    return result;
}

void sl_free(slist *strings) {
    while(strings) {
        slist *tmp = strings;
        strings = strings->next;
        if(tmp->sref->n)
            tmp->sref->n--;
        else {
            free(tmp->sref->s);
            free(tmp->sref);
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
}

slist *sl_shallow_copy(slist *strings){
    slist *shallow = NULL;
    for(slist **c = &shallow; strings; strings = strings->next, c = &(*c)->next) {
        *c = malloc(sizeof **c);
        if(!*c) {
             sl_free(shallow);
             return NULL;
        }
        (*c)->sref = strings->sref;
        (*c)->sref->n++;
        (*c)->next = NULL;
    }
    return shallow;
}

void sl_print(slist *strings) {
    if(!strings)
        return;
    printf("%s (%zu)", strings->sref->s, strings->sref->n);
    strings = strings->next;
    for(; strings; strings = strings->next)
        printf(" %s (%zu)", strings->sref->s, strings->sref->n);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    slist *s = sl_cons("hello", sl_cons("world", sl_cons("!", NULL)));
    sl_print(s);
    slist *s2 = sl_shallow_copy(s);
    sl_print(s2);
    sl_free(s2);
    sl_free(s);
}
```

example output:

```
hello (0) world (0) ! (0)
hello (1) world (1) ! (1)
```

Comment: UB = Undefined Behavior (i.e. anything can happen)

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Spelled out on first use.  Thanks.

Comment: The reference count doesn't look quite right yet. `sl_cons` initializes it to 1 when it is allocated, but `sl_free` does not free it when it is 1.

Comment: @AllanWind Why `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` for a non-posix question?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `strdup()` requires it on Linux.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks!  I started out with using `n = 1` but then realized that you might as well start at `0`.  I apparently forgot to synchronized my local  change to`sl_cons()` to here.  valgrind reports no issues with the latest revision.